# Unicode 8 digits plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, unicode

I need to **plot 8-digits Unicode char in chart of Matplotlib**. I tried

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c='white', edgecolor='#3b5998', marker=f'$\U0001F9F8$', alpha=.25, s=120)
```

But do not work... Any help is very welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you enclosing a unicode character in mathtext?

Comment: A emoji needs to have glyph for this to work. For example this will work `plt.scatter(x, y, s=area,marker = "$♥$")` but `plt.scatter(x, y, s=area,marker = "$$")` this won't

Comment: Sorry for my earlier comment:  @Equinox is correct - the problem here is that you do not have that glyph.  It may be possible to change your font to one that contains the glyph.  I get `Font 'rm' does not have a glyph for '\U0001f9f8' `

Comment: Thank you! I converted to image and plotted as png.